# How to prevent repeating the same option value of a selection in a php loop

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

```
public function getProductById(Request $request)
    {
        $response = '';
        $product = Product::find($request->productId);
        $groups = Group::all();

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            if ($group->id == $product->group_id) {
                //exclude this record

                $response .= "<option value='" . $group->id . "'>";
                $response .= $group->group_name;
                $response .= "</option>";
            }
            
        }
    }
```

This is my function.I'm getting the product record by sending the product id, and from that I'm getting the relevant group record of the product.And I looped through all groups and I want to exclude the record of the group which is the group_id I got from the product table.I'm really stucked here.Apperciate your help thanks.

Comment: Replace `if ($group->id == $product->group_id) {` with `if ($group->id != $product->group_id) {` ?

Comment: @Marleen write as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
public function getProductById(Request $request)
    {
        $response = '';
        $product = Product::find($request->productId);
        $groups = Group::all();

        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            if ($group->id != $product->group_id) {
                //exclude this record

                $response .= "<option value='" . $group->id . "'>";
                $response .= $group->group_name;
                $response .= "</option>";
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better to not get the record in the first place

```
public function getProductById(Request $request)
    {
        $product = Product::find($request->productId);
        $groups = Group::where('id','!=' $product->group_id)->get();


        foreach ($groups as $group) {
                $response .= "<option value='" . $group->id . "'>";
                $response .= $group->group_name;
                $response .= "</option>";
            }
            
        }
    }
```

and then better to loop over groups in the blade file instead of here

```
    @foreach($groups as $group)
       <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
```